# Using emit to trigger an EnhancedGrid event

Tags: javascript, grid, dojo

It seems there is a bug in the `dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid`. The `"onApplyCellEdit"` is not triggered on editing a cell and then clicking Ok button in IE browser. Here is a jsfiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/eZVkA/3/

As you can see, when you edit the cells in second column and then click on the button (without pressing enter or clicking on the grid), the `"onApplyCellEdit"` is triggered in all the browsers except IE. I presume this is a bug.

I am trying to resolve this by using `emit` function but not sure how to use it properly. I wish to use `emit` on click event of the button and trigger the `"onApplyCellEdit"` of the `EnhancedGrid`.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need emit but it is a good function to learn though.
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/on.html

by calling grid.edit.apply(); it will trigger the event. Grid is referring to the widget itself.